# Como usar uma variável declarada dentro de uma função, em outra função?

Tags: javascript

Quero usar a variavel cpf em outra função!!

```js
function enviar(){

    var nome = document.getElementById('input_Nome').value
    var cpf= document.getElementById('input_Cpf').value
    var  data_de_nascimento = document.getElementById('input_DataDeNascimento').value
    var  endereço = document.getElementById('input_Endereço').value
    var res = document.getElementById('res')
    var fsex = document.getElementsByName('radsex') 
    var fdeficiencia = document.getElementsByName('rad_deficiencia')
    var genero = ''
    var deficiencia = ''

        if (fsex[0].checked){
            genero = 'Homem'
        }else if (fsex[1].checked){
            genero= 'Mulher'
        }

        if(fdeficiencia[0].checked){
            deficiencia = 'Sim'
        }else if(fdeficiencia[1].checked){
            deficiencia= 'Não'
        }       

        
}
```

Comment: Declara fora dela...

Comment: Olá e bem vindo ao StackOverflow, antes de realizar perguntas por favor dê uma olhada nesse [link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas?cb=1) de como não fazer perguntas, isso ajudará você a ter um maior índice de aceitação na sua pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variável declarada com `var` dentro de uma função só terá escopo dentro dessa função. Como está explícito que você deseja atribuir um valor à variável `cpf` ao chamar a função onde ela está, não faz sentido tentar reaproveitar o valor dessa variável em outra função, a não ser que você declarasse a variável com escopo global:

```
var cpf;
function enviar(){
   cpf= document.getElementById('input_Cpf').value
}
```

Mesmo assim a variável `cpf` só teria algum valor se a função `enviar()` fosse chamada antes da outra função.

Mas como é bom evitar variáveis globais, não tem muito sentido fazer isso. Basta você usar outra variável pegando o mesmo valor que `cpf` pega dentro da função `enviar()`:

```
function enviar(){
   var cpf= document.getElementById('input_Cpf').value
}

function outraFuncao(){
   var cpf= document.getElementById('input_Cpf').value
}
```

Os valores de `cpf` nas duas funções serão os mesmos e atualizados de acordo com o valor que estiver no elemento `#input_Cpf`.

Comment: Então boto mais um gatilho no meu botão pra disparar a outra função?

Comment: Não há nenhum botão na pergunta.